# How to resize an image using WebImage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying resize an image using WebImage but I need that all sides are equals, example: `width: 200 and height: 200`, but after save the image not keeps does proportions its change to `200x65` for example. How could I do this ?

trying.

```
public class SaveImage{

    public static void save(HttpPostedFileBase image, String pathFile, String imgName){        
        String extension = Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
        String pathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pathFile);
        WebImage wi = new WebImage(image.InputStream);        
        wi.Resize(width:200, height:200, preserveAspectRatio:true, preventEnlarge:true);
        String imgToSave = Path.Combine(pathToSave, imgName + extension);
        wi.Save(imgToSave);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem, I did: `wi.Resize(width:200, height:200, preserveAspectRatio:false, preventEnlarge:false);` and it works fine.